# OpenSSL certificate validation caching

Tags: ssl, curl, openssh

I make a HTTPS request with CURL. CURL uses SSL and checks the server certificate. This works fine.

It is possible to simulate a web browser behavior, that means that the certificate is checked if the first HTTPS connection is made, but the following HTTPS connections to the same server don't check the certificate again. The certificate check is cached by the web browser.

Comment: Browser don't cache the validation itself, they resume an existing SSL session.

Comment: Thats right. If the browser need a second connection to the same server then he opens a new HTTPS connection. Checks the browser the certificate again?

Comment: In my experience the browser will throw some very strange errors if you replace the certificate during an open browser session. So I guess it will it least check if the certificate has been changed.

Comment: Thats an interesting test. For me, it looks like an implementation bug aka performance feature in the web browser.